# How to use keras functional api with def? Getting error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'layers' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to use KerasRegressor with my model:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed_value)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, input_var, output_var, cv=kfold)
```

In a tutorial, to create the model, this is used:

```
def create_model():

    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

    return model
```

It worked. However, when I am trying to use the functional keras instead of the sequential one:

```
def create_model():

    # create model
    #Start defining the input tensor:
    input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))

    #create the layers and pass them the input tensor to get the output tensor:

    hidden1Out = Dense(units=2, activation='relu')(input_data)
    finalOut = Dense(units=2, activation='relu')(hidden1Out)

    output = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='u')(finalOut)  


    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

    return model
```

I got the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'layers' referenced before assignment"

It happens at:

```
input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))
```

So what's wrong with it? how do I solve it?

Comment: What is the layers variable in this code? It would be better to include a full example that produces the error.

Comment: Sorry, full def model updated.

Comment: I did not ask for the model, I asked for code that reproduces the problem, specially about the layers variable.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is gona work but try using [global](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/global.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remove all the useless comments and redundant code before copying it to stackoverflow. Then I realised something missing in my code:

model = Model(input_data,outputs = output)

So after putting it in:

```
def create_model():

    # create model
    #Start defining the input tensor:
    input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))

    #create the layers and pass them the input tensor to get the output tensor:

    hidden1Out = Dense(units=2, activation='relu')(input_data)
    finalOut = Dense(units=2, activation='relu')(hidden1Out)

    output = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='u')(finalOut)  

    model = Model(input_data,outputs = output)

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

    return model
```

I finally got it working! Thanks Matias Valdenegro, alsaibi anyway.